# How do is disable the past time in dropdown if the date is today?

Tags: php

I could not disable the past time in the dropdown if the date is today.
Can anyone help me?

I have successfully shown all the time in the dropdown.

```
<?php
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$explode = explode(' ',$currentDate);
$time = $explode[1];
list($h,$m,$s) = explode(':',$time);
for($hours=8; $hours<22; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) // the interval for mins is '30'

        echo '<option>'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'
           .str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'
           .str_pad($sec=0,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);'</option>';
?>
```

I expect the output is if the date is today and the current system time is 10:00:00 then the past time in the dropdown is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your for loop you can do a check to see if the current time is greater than the time you are echoing for the option. You can then use this to set a variable for disabled.

```
<?php

for ($hours=8; $hours<22; $hours++) {
    for ($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) {
        $optTime = strtotime($hours.':'. $mins . ':00');
        $curTime = strtotime(date('H:i:s'));
        $disabled = "";
        if ($optTime <= $curTime) {
            $disabled ='disabled';
        }

        echo '<option ' . $disabled . '>'.str_pad($hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).':'
           .str_pad($mins, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).':'
           .str_pad($sec=0, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        '</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Jeemusu, really appreciate it.